# mongoDB, ReactJs, sending a request to find a user using AXIOS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

I'm now learning reactJS, and how to use axios to get data from the database(mongoDB),
I'm stuck right now when I want to get data from the DB by using the find() meted.

I don't know way, but the request is working (I can see that on the console log), but I can't find the way to get the data inside my react app.

Here is the code

```
        this.state = {
         username: '079joseph',
         password: '079Mjoseph'
    }
}

checkUserDetails=()=>{
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/findUser/' + this.state)
    .then(user=>{
        window.localStorage.setItem('moviesAccount', JSON.stringify(user))
        })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

what's happening is that the request is fine, but I'm not getting back any data, (when I'm trying that request on POSTMAN I'm getting back the details of the user.

Here is my module code for that request

```
    router.route('/findUser/:userDetails').get((req, res)=>{
User.find({username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password})
.then(user =>  res.json(user), console.log('good'))
.catch(err => res.status(400).json('eror ' + err))
```

})

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should use req.params.userDetails.username and same as for password. You requesting GET method and the userDetails is parameter. Please check for it

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Actually I'm getting a empty array for the res.

Comment: can you print your "req" object on console. Then you can be sure on the data is coming properly.

Comment: If I'm using req.params.userDetails.username then I'm not getting back any data, I'm getting a empty array!

Comment: You have to print your req object to console where request on server handled. Just add console.log(req) and see whats goin on.

Comment: I'm getting the req. when I'm printing it on the console, but the res. I'm not getting